# Правильно ли писать два css кода для PC и Phone

Tags: css, html5

Здравствуйте недавно осознал что верстать сайт лишь для PC — дело неблагодарное и решил делать адаптивные сайты

Вопрос
Правильно ли писать 2 css кода ?

Один с ограничением    `@media (max-width:767px) {}`

Другой с ограничением `@media (min-width:767px) {}`

Comment: Max 767, min 768. А вообще посмотрите как работают сетки (тот же Bootstrap).

Comment: Можно и так делать. Только цифры на одну должны отличаться, иначе в одной точке 767 будет два стиля. Но нет конкретного числа, где телефон отличается от десктопа, поэтому таких точек может быть много. Бывает для каждого блока сайта их много своих.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код может быть общим для разных разрешений. Разные разрешения могут содержать измененные элементы основного, или полностью другой. Ширина экрана может быть разной, сколько угодно. Потому что это инструмент, чтобы создавать нужные дизайны.
Как писать код - полностью изолированные или частичный с основным - решать только вам. Проще говоря можно писать как угодно.